# is it possible to call a function without it's name?

Tags: java

I tried calling a function in my code, but i get a blank screen only.

```
class Addition
{
    public void add(){
    int a=20;
    int b=30;
    int c=a+b;
    System.out.println("Addition of a and b is: " +c);
    }
 }
public class Methodcall
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Addition call=new Addition();

    }
}
```

I expect the addition of a & b 
But all i get is just a blank screen only

Comment: No, it’s not possible. After you instantiate an instance of the Addition class, you must call its add method to get the behavior you want.  You could move the logic to the construct or, but that’s not what it’s for.

Comment: place the code in your add() into Addition's constructor then you will see the addition of a & b, but better not to do it in this way.

Comment: No its not possible, from the obvious reasons- imagine you have more methods in the class eg. simply `add`, `div`, `multiply`, for instance. Well, how afterwards after initialization with `Addition call = new Addition();` (create new instance) will program know which method you are assuming it will use? Theoretically, you can create custom constructor and make the calculation there directly, or call this method directly in constructor, then it will work as you wrote, but `its a really BAD practice and you should avoid it in this case` (its not the purpose of it)

Comment: Btw you can create `static` method, then you dont need to make the instance of the class- its kind of "shared" across all instances and should be used for static things which do not modify any class variable, etc.. (simplified)- static method can be called (once it will be in place) like `Addition.add()` directly

Answer (score 2):

The code wouldn't do what you're expecting it to do:

In your `main` function, you're only instantiating the `Addition` object. Think of it as creating the object:

```
Addition call = new Addition();
```

If you want it to *do something*, in your case to add `a` and `b` and print the result, you will need to call the method:

```
call.add();
```

As others have mentioned, you *could* put it in the constructor, but that's not what the constructor is meant for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Addition call=new Addition();
 call.add();
```

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes I  gave it just for an example

Comment: Without warning, you should never give such advices (or examples), especially to obvious beginners!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes will neglect this in future